# How can you toggle comments with VSCode in Linux?

Tags: linux, comments, visual-studio-code

I've usually used Sublime Text for editing JavaScript files, there I can toggle comments with `Ctrl+Shift+7|/`.

Now I'm trying VSCode, which is a great project. But I failed in toggling comments per shortcut. The documentation says: [Ctrl+K and the like](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/keybindings), but this did not work.

Any suggestions?

---

I'm using Ubuntu 14 with Gnome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can toggle comments with `CTRL + #`.

Comment: Wow, how did you figure out this? It toggles line comments, any advice for block comments?

Comment: I simply tried ;-)
I don't know how to toggle this `/* */`. But `CTRL+#` works also for blocks.

Comment: That's worth committing to memory. It should be listed in the key bindings list somewhere as well.

Answer (score 5):

`CTRL+K` then `CTRL+C` to comment and `CTRL+K` then `CTRL+U` to uncomment. Works for Gnu/Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Gnome...

Comment: Unfortunately not on my System: Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 4):

Tipp: Press F1 and type the name of the command you are looking for - it will show the keybinding. Bonus: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/keybindings explains many shortcuts and how to customise them.

Answer (score 2):

Use:  `CTRL + /`

This works for the current version using Arch linux.
These additional comments are to bring the character count up to thirty.

Comment: please clarify "current version of Arch Linux" by providing version number. (From Review).

Answer (score 0):

VS Code keyboard bindings are "context sensitive". That means that they apply only if some conditions apply.

To see (and eventually change) the keybindings in your installation go to Preferences (`Ctrl+Shift+P`), enter "shortcuts" and select "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts". There you'll see not only the actual keybindings on your system but the conditions "when" they apply.

You'll see also that there are different "Commands" for handling comments:

- Add Line Comment `Ctrl+K Ctrl+C`
- Remove Line Comment `Ctrl+K Ctrl+U`
- Toggle Line Comment `Ctrl+Shift+7`
- Toggle Block Comment `Ctrl+Shift+A`

Pleas notice that the keybindings might differ on different operating systems (Windows, Linux etc.)

For more details see the VS Code documentation on [keybindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)